# Notepad++ regex to replace underscores in href link's anchor text

Tags: regex, notepad++

Given:

```
<a href="http://mysite/dir/Part_1_in_200.html"/>Part_1_in_200</a>  
<a href="http://mysite/dir/Part_2_in_200.html"/>Part_2_in_200</a>
etc
```

Goal:

```
<a href="http://mysite/dir/Part_1_in_200.html"/>Part 1 in 200</a>  
<a href="http://mysite/dir/Part_2_in_200.html"/>Part 2 in 200</a>
etc
```

I am trying to replace the underscores from the anchor text with a space in Notepad++.
 I tried to replace `(?<=\>)\_(?=\<)` OR `(?<=\>)_(?=\<)` with `\s` but none of them work.

Please help, much appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not perfect, but you can try:

```
Find: <a([^>]+)>([^<]*?)_([^<]*)</a>
Replace: <a$1>$2 $3</a>
```

Keep pressing "Replace All" until there are no more matches. If there are too many occurrences, you can press and hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.